# .gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am new to Gwt i am trying to create a web application and invoke it using an maven plugin. But the problem is during invocation of code server i am getting an error like  **unable to find xxxx..gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?**  I have tried to add the .gwt.xml file into class path in serveral ways like include additional classpath etc.., but nothing helps... is there is any way to add it to the maven class path.

Comment: You should maybe show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the gwt-maven-plugin is not able to find the configured module.
    Please see the configuration of this plugin in the pom.xml, i.e. the section:

```
    <modules>
        <!-- this refers to xxxx..gwt.xml -->
        <module>xxxx</module>
    </modules>
```

If you cant resolve the problem you could compare your project with a minimal working "Hello-World-GWT-Project".
You could create such a template-project with a maven archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.7.0
```

Comment: I got this error after forgetting to uncomment one of the modules.  Oops!  :-)  This answer was still very useful though because it pointed me to the XML file.  I didn't end up wasting a lot of time on what could have been easily overlooked since it was such a silly mistake.